# cant load image in tkinter using PhotoImage

Tags: python-3.x, image, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
can=Canvas(window,width=500,height=500,bg="sky blue")
can.pack()
filename=PhotoImage(file="//home//maklab-embedded//Desktop//download.png")
image=can.create_image(0,0,anchor=SW,image=filename)
window.mainloop()
```

This code not gives any error output but it not showing any image on canvas.How can i solve it??

Comment: Try `anchor=NW` instead.  Your code put the image above the top side so it cannot be seen.

Comment: Why are you using two slashes in the path?

Answer (score 0):

The canvas coordinate 0,0 is at the top-left of the canvas. When you put something at 0,0 with an anchor of "sw", that means that the bottom of the object is at the very top of the canvas, and the object extends up beyond the visible part of the canvas.

You need to either use different coordinates or use an anchor of "nw" so that the top-left portion of the image is at the top-left portion of the canvas.